# React toggle active class between button group array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I made a photo gallery with a filter for categories, but I want to make the active category button to have the `active` class

I display the buttons by mapping through the `galleryData` array

```
{
  galleryData.map((item, index) => (
    <button
      key={index}
      onClick={() => filterGalley(item.category)}
      className="filter-button"
    >
      {item.category}
    </button>
  ));
}
```

And onClick I filter the gallery items by category. The `value` is a string of category type

```
const filterGalley = (value) => {
  if (value === "all") {
    setGalleryItems(galleryData);
    return;
  }

  const filteredData = galleryData.filter((item) => item.category === value);

  console.log(value);
  setGalleryItems(filteredData);
};
```

How can I pass the `active` class to the currently viewed category? onMount should be `all` and after that the one that's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Define a state for activeCategory and use it for `active` class:

```
const [activeCategory, setActiveCategory] = useState('all');
const filterGalley = (value) => {
    setActiveCategory(value);
    if (value === 'all') {
        setGalleryItems(galleryData);
        return;
    }

    const filteredData = galleryData.filter(
        (item) => item.category === value
    );

    console.log(value);
    setGalleryItems(filteredData);
};
```

And use it:

```
 {galleryData.map((item, index) => (
   <button
       key={index}
       onClick={() => filterGalley(item.category)}
       className={"filter-button " + (activeCategory === item.category ? 'active' : '')}
   >
       {item.category}
   </button>
))}
```